# Looping in the Array Prototype

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, prototype

Why does not my code work?

```
var canyonCows = [
  {name: "Bessie", type: "cow", hadCalf: "Burt"},
  {name: "Donald", type: "bull", hadCalf: null},
  {name: "Esther", type: "calf", hadCalf: null},
  {name: "Burt", type: "calf", hadCalf: null},
  {name: "Sarah", type: "cow", hadCalf: "Esther"},
  {name: "Samson", type: "bull", hadCalf: null},
  {name: "Delilah", type: "cow", hadCalf: null}
];

Array.prototype.countCattle = function(type){
  var counter = 0;
  for(var i=0;i<this.lenght;i++){
    if (this[i]["type"]==type){
      counter++;
    }
  }
  return counter;
};

console.log(canyonCows.countCattle("cow"));
```

When I run it I get the output of `0` instead of `3`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You've typo'd `lenght`. Therefore `i<undefined === true`, and your loop isn't executing.

Comment: is this from CodeSchool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's `length` not lenght.

Here the loop won't work due to the spelling mistake.